# IBMQ.load_account() is failing

Tags: programming, qiskit

When I try `IBMQ.load_account` or `IBMQ.delete_account` gives an error in the ubuntu machine and the error is,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqfactory.py", line 291, in delete_account
    stored_credentials, _ = read_credentials_from_qiskitrc()
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/credentials/configrc.py", line 86, in read_credentials_from_qiskitrc
    new_credentials = Credentials(**single_credentials)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'efault_provider'
```

The qiskit version I used is

```
{'qiskit-terra': '0.17.4',
 'qiskit-aer': '0.8.2',
 'qiskit-ignis': '0.6.0',
 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.14.0',
 'qiskit-aqua': '0.9.2',
 'qiskit': '0.27.0', 
 'qiskit-nature': None,
 'qiskit-finance': None,
 'qiskit-optimization': None,
 'qiskit-machine-learning': None}
```

Comment: Are you just calling that function or something else?

Comment: Hi @epelaaez , I tried first to save the account it gave me the same error. So I tried deleting the account again I ended up with the same error. I'm calling the function by importing IBMQ from qiskit along with my credential.

Comment: In the last line of the error message, the parameter `efault_provider` is mentioned. Is this a typo from your side or is that the actual error message?

Comment: It is the actual error message right. Because we save the account using `ibmq.save_account('Key', overwrite = True)` which means it is an actual error message and not a typo.

Comment: @Monica could you post contents of your `~/.qiskit/qiskitrc` file here? (hide the token before posting)

Comment: Thank you @RathishCholarajan for your response, I followed the instructions given by jyu00 and it worked.

Comment: Great! Yup I was going to check if your qiskitrc file had 'efault_provider' and suggest the same fix :) glad it works now!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'efault_provider'
```

Your `qiskitrc` file contains an invalid keyword `efault_provider` (it should be `default_provider`). You'll need to delete your `$HOME/.qiskit/qiskitrc` file and do `save_account()` again.

Comment: Thank you @jyu00, I deleted the file and it worked for me.